# Azure recommends creating an index of [VersionedFields] table in SQL Database

Tags: azure, sql-database

I was recently checking a SQL Database in Azure and noticed this recommendation:

[image: database index recommendation]

[image: recommendation details]

According to the Microsoft docs on ["create index" recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-advisor-implement-performance-recommendations?view=azuresql), they do have mechanisms in place to ensure that the creation of the index won't be a problem in terms of available CPU, Data IO, Log IO, and available storage.

I found some helpful infomation in an [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1793/946) to another question which states:

> SQL Azure monitors the use of the system and the query plans it generates and tries to work out whether the plans could benefit from additional indexes. When it thinks it has one, it makes the suggestion. If you elect to implement the suggestion it will run some tests to ensure it has actually made an improvement, and will roll back if it hasn't.
> We implement almost all the suggestions it offers. Indexes are generally not material to the operation of a database so they're safe to add, with a few critical exceptions (like clustered and unique indexes).
> For the most part, as long as your DB tier offers you sufficient storage, we recommend adding any index suggested with either a Medium or High Impact rating.

Is this a safe and recommended action? Are there any necessary precautions?